# Gas phase chiral molecules

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, chirality

Are there any molecules that are chiral that are also gases at room temperature?

Failing that, what chiral molecules have a high vapor pressure? Propylene oxide has a boiling point of only 34 C, so that seems like a good one. Are there others?

EDIT: I appreciate all of the great suggestions! I should have mentioned before, but I am looking for something that can be purchased in both R and S enantiomers.

Comment: Chances look slim. Bromochlorofluoromethane has a bp of 41.2 deg C according to Chemspider. Looking at the HCFC page of Wikipedia doesn't hit paydirt.

Answer (score 5):

The molecule has to be small. *trans*-1,2-difluorocyclopropane is certainly chiral, and its predicted boiling point is ~ 5 deg C.  *trans*-1,1,2,3-tetrafluorocyclopropane is another likely candidate.  This one will be easier to prepare (from perfluoropropylene oxide and *trans*-1,2-difluoroethylene).

Separation of enantiomers is the hard part.

Comment: Sorry, you lost me, what is "trans-1,1,2,3-tetrafluoroethylene"

Comment: It's tetrafluorocyclopropane.  Note to self: don't post without coffee.

Answer (score 4):

[1-Chloro-1,2,2,2-tetrafluoroethane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-Chloro-1,2,2,2-tetrafluoroethane) has bp -12 Celsium. For comparison, [1-chloro-1-fluoroethane](http://www.chemicalbook.com/ChemicalProductProperty_US_CB7446771.aspx) has bp +16 Celsium. In most cases, replacing good share of hydrogen in an organic molecule with fluorine leads to significant decrease of bp. [perfluoropropylene oxide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexafluoropropylene_oxide)  has bp -27 Celsium, comparing to +34 of vanilla propylene oxide you noted.

Answer (score 4):

**Considering molecules that have been prepared and resolved:**

**1,3-dimethylallene** (2,3-pentadiene) boils a bit above room temperature at 48.5 C (see  page 11 of this [reference](https://scholarspace.manoa.hawaii.edu/bitstream/handle/10125/11395/uhm_phd_6713714_r.pdf?sequence=1) for the experimental preparation), but likely has a reasonable vapor pressure since it has a lower molecular weight than pentane.  The advantage to this molecule is that it has already been (at least) partially resolved (see [here](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01026a032?journalCode=jacsat) and [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040403900898305)) in a one-step hydroboration.

Another simple hydrocarbon to consider is ***trans*-cyclooctene**.  It has a higher boiling point (143 C) but a significant vapor pressure, it flashes at 25 C.  The molecule is chiral and has also been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

If you use deuterium and tritium, you can make stereocenters from methyl groups. For example, 1-deutero-1-tritioethane is be chiral.